# Dojo: Swapping two different views in a Single Page Application

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I´m new to dojo and I´m want to do the following:

Pretend you have a single page application but you have two views, which are built up totally different. One view is e.g. a startpage which would just fill the Bordercontainer-center. The second view would rather look like a standard webapp, with a header in the Bordercontainer-top, a menu in Bordercontainer-left and some content in Bordercontainer-center.

If the index.html (single page app) is now called I want the startpage to appeare first. There should be an onclick-event in it. With this event the views should change. This means the startpage disappears and the second webapp-view is shown.

What would be the best way to implement this?

I thought of using two Bordercontainers.
The first Bordercontainer would contain the startpage in the region center.
The second Bordercontainer would contain the webapp-view (top, left, center).
Would it now be possible to swap the center region from the frist Bordercontainer in a way that the startpage get´s swaped with the second Bordercontainer? Would this be a way how to solve my approach? 
If yes I would need some kind of controller which would swap the view.
Could I solve this with using dojo.wire?

Or is there a straight forward approach in dojo, which I have not found yet?
If there is a small example or tutorial out there, it would be great to receive a link to it.

Thx for every hint.

Comment: If the start page is "only a center region", then why even use a BorderContainer for it?  There are various ways to answer this question, one would be to use a StackContainer as a container for your start and main widgets, and just call `selectChild` when you want to switch.

Comment: I think you can take a look at [mobile view controller](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/mobile/ViewController.html), which I think is what you are looking for. Even though it is for a Mobile web app, it should at least give you a start in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code:

```js
require([
  "dijit/form/Button"
], function() {

  changeView = function(idShow, idHide) {

    var showView = dojo.byId(idShow);
    var showHide = dojo.byId(idHide);
    if (showView.style.display == 'block') {
      showView.style.display = 'none';
      showHide.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      showView.style.display = 'block';
      showHide.style.display = 'none';
    }
  };
});
```

```css
#view1 {
  display: block;
}
#view2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Change View</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/resources/dojo.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css" media="screen" />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js" data-dojo-config="isDebug: true, parseOnLoad: true"></script>

</head>

<body class="tundra">
  <div id="view1">
    View1
    <br>
    <button dojoType="Button" widgetId="view1Button" onClick="changeView('view2', 'view1');">Change to View2</button>
  </div>

  <div id="view2">
    View2
    <br>
    <button dojoType="Button" widgetId="view2Button" onClick="changeView('view1', 'view2');">Change to View1</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This lets me change the view with onclick and css and a little js.

I think this is one of the various ways you mentioned, for solving my approach. But what I think I´m missing now is to combine my function `changeView` with dojo - somehow.

What would be the right way to combine dojo and the function `changeView` now?

Would I write a dojo modul with a `define` and then work with it in my html and calling it with `require`?

Or generally.. for a dojo-beginner.

If I need javascript code for my app, is there a straight forward way to combine this with dojo?

e.g. with any kind of approuch

1. Look an see what dojo has to solve the approch
2. Write JS code, if there is no suitable dojo modul/function yet
3. Think about seperating the JS code it into modules
4. Write the modules in dojo with `define`
5. Use the modules in the app by calling them with `require`

Would this be a proper way for programming in dojo?

The question is more a general "howto glue JS and dojo together" to write webapps and use the advantages of dojo.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at dojox/mobile (http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/mobile.html) it has support for what you are trying to do.  You could also look at dojox/app (http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/app.html or http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/dojox_app/contactsList/) to see if that gives you what you need.